# Xpath 1.0 select first node back to ancestor

Tags: xpath

My XML as below :

```
<Query>
  <Comp>
    <Pers>
        <Emp>
            <Job>
                <Code>Not selected</Code>
            </Job>
        </Emp>
        <Emp>
            <Job>
                <Code>selected</Code>
            </Job>
        </Emp>
    </Pers>
  </Comp>
</Query>
```

I have an XPath : /Query/Comp/Pers/Emp/Job[Code='selected']/../../../..

The result should only have one < Emp > that meet condition

```
<Query>
  <Comp>
    <Pers>
        <Emp>
            <Job>
                <Code>selected</Code>
            </Job>
        </Emp>
    </Pers>
  </Comp>
</Query>
```

How could I get the result?
The system doesn't work with ancestor::*. I have to use '/..' to populate the ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use `ancestor` here to get the `<emp>` tag, the following expath should select any `<emp>` tag that meets your criteria:

`/Query/Comp/Pers/Emp[Job[Code='selected']]`

Note: You say your result should be one, which will be correct in this case but this expression will return *all* nodes that match your criteria

---

**Edit:**

You've stated you're using XSLT and you've given me a bit of a snippet below, but I'm still not 100% sure of your actual structure. You can use the XPath to identify all the nodes that are not equal to `selected`, and then use XSLT to copy everything except those.

```
// Copy's all nodes in the input to the output
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

// Matches specifically the Emp records that are not equal to selected and 
// applies no action to them to they do not appear in the output
<xsl:template match="/Query/Comp/Pers/Emp[Job[Code!='selected']]" />
```

The two templates above would transform your input to your desired output!

Comment: Thanks @Dan Gardner. I tried your XPath, the result was <Emp> <Job> <Code>. But I need the result populate all nodes from <Query> tag. for ie :<Query><Comp><Pers><Emp><Job><Code>selected</Code></Job></Emp></Pers></Query>

Comment: Ah okay I understand now sorry. I don't believe what you are asking is possible, XPath can only select entire node trees, it can't manipulate the structure it returns. It would be possible to achieve what you wanted using an XSLT, I could help with the structure of that if you like? Could you provide any more detail around the larger problem you are trying to solve, I could maybe make some suggestions for an alternative approach!

Comment: I using an XSLT before the XPath for the filter. I tried not to change the XSLT. Since the  XPath is not possible. I need to adjust the mapping in XSLT.

Comment: @Handy are you able to post the XSLT code? I can either edit my answer to explain and use the XSLT, or you could answer you own question with an explanation so others with the same question in the future can see the solution :)

Comment: Here is my simple XSLT code to select the first row based on match criteria. <xsl:for-each select="Query/Comp/Pers/Emp/Job[Code='selected'][1]">

Comment: @Handy updated the answer with some XSLT snippets, let me know how it goes!

Comment: @Handy any luck with the XSLT?